# Cocos2D: Play Sound on Touches Moved

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, simpleaudioengine

I currently have a dial that rotates on touch.  I would like to include a "click" sound effect when the dial is moving.  I have the click sound working, but it is a bit chaotic.

I currently put this in my touches moved:
`[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"ButtonClick.m4a"];`

But when I rotate the dial the sound effects goes crazy (i.e. CLICKCLICKLICKCLICKCLICK...) when i would like to to do this: Click..Click..Click..Click..Click..

Instead of the "click" sound restarting at each movement of the dial, how can I achieve a "click" sound that finishes the full sound file and starts over each time (i.e. loop)?